# git missing on redhat desktop edition

Tags: git, redhat, yum

git appears to be missing from Redhat 6.5 Client edition.

yum search and install were both fruitless. any advice for configuring yum to allow me to install this software as a package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is related to here:
https://superuser.com/questions/631268/rhel-desktop-how-to-install-g/

The optional rpms repository has to be enabled manually in a non obvious way.
In:
/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo

change the 0 to 1 for enabled in the
[rhel-6-desktop-optional-rpms]

section

Answer (score 0):

It's in desktop-optional-rpms:

```
subscription-manager register
subscription-manager subscribe
subscription-manager  repos  --enable rhel-7-desktop-optional-rpms
yum install git
```